# Self tracking poco

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a poco class like this

```
public Profile
{
    public virtual int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual bool Enabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

When i try to update like this

```
var prof = new Profile(){ ID = 1, Enabled = false };
context.Profiles.Single (s => s.ID == 1);
context.Profiles.ApplyCurrentValues(prof);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Sql says to me that Description does not allow NULL, but i'm not updating the "Description" column, I want to update just the "Enabled" field.

What's wrong?

Tks

Comment: Within your update code, does the second line change the object that the third line works on?  It really _seems_ like the second line does nothing to affect the third line (at least, that's how I'd expect it to work).

Comment: Austin, the second line is to relate my detached register with the persisted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var prof = new Profile { ID = 1, Enabled = false };
// Attach prof as unchanged entity
context.Profiles.Attach(prof);
// Get state entry for prof
ObjectStateEntry entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(prof);
// Set only Enabled property to changed
entry.SetModifiedProperty("Enabled");
context.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see I didn't need to load the entity first from database. I was able to set which property was modified on detached entity.

Comment: It works, tks. I'm considering change the t4 template to add entry.SetModifiedProperty("PropName"); on all properties, what do you think ?

Comment: Then it will be same as setting whole entity to modified state = all properties will be updated.

Comment: Yes but i'll only call entry.SetModifiedProperty("PropName") if the value of property has changed

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment:  Without knowing EF4, this is how I'd expect it to work:

```
var prof = context.Profiles.Single (s => s.ID == 1);
prof.Enabled = false;
context.Profiles.ApplyCurrentValues(prof);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Assuming `Single` is the Linq Single, then it will return a value that you should modify.

Comment: This way works but ef is still generating update for all columns

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
var prof = context.Profiles.Single(s => s.ID == 1);
prof.Enabled = false;
context.SaveChanges();
```

I think the problem is that you're calling ApplyCurrentValues from an untracked object - this means that it has no idea which properties have and haven't been changed, so it just copies across **all** the properties, including the ones that are null - in your case Description.

You don't need to call ApplyCurrentValues if you are modifying the values of an entity that is loaded from the data context.

Comment: It works but my end user doesn't have access to data context. My business class get the entity detached